# Modify HTTP Post Data on the fly Burp Proxy?

Tags: proxy

i want to modify the Post Data of an Java Applet on the fly. 
Tamper Data can't modify Post requests of an Java Applet, so i had to use a proxy (in my case burp suite free). 
The applet sends a post request for ex.  foobar.com/index.?foo=10000&bar=1000

I need to change this values (too short time periode to do this by hand).
Burp Proxy has a great "match and replace" funktion to use regex to replace strings but if have to use the old string in my case.

I need a solution to do this:
foo += 123
bar += 1000;

Any idea? Thanks!

Comment: I just wrote me a php script to edit these values and forward the request but how do i "match and replace" the url of the call?

Answer (score 1):

I use Paros Proxy to trap the request. Once trapped you can modify the request along with cookie and POST/GET data and then untrap it. I am sure it is possible with Burrp too.

Comment: I have to edit this data automaticly because these are time critical